# Выполнение методов класса в разных потоках

Tags: python, многопоточность, классы, pyqt, qthread

Имеется примерно такой код:

```
class MyClass(QObject):
    def method1(self):
        for i in round(1, 1000000):
            pass
       
    def method2(self):
        for i in round(1, 1000000):
            pass

class GuiClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        mc = MyClass()

    def start(self):
        """вызвать self.mc.method1 и self.mc.method2 в разных потоках"""
        """оба метода одного экземпляра"""
```

---

Вызов метода `start()` должен запустить методы `method1()` и `method2()` одного экземпляра в разных потоках.

---

**P.S.** 
Раскидать методы `method1()` и `method2()` по разным классам не подходит для меня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто решил визуализировать вашу задачу.
Попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import threading

class MyClass(QtCore.QObject):
    dataMethod1 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    dataMethod2 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def method1(self, maxMethod1):
        for i in range(0, maxMethod1):
            self.dataMethod1.emit(i)
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(10)

    def method2(self, maxMethod2):
        for i in range(1, maxMethod2):
            self.dataMethod2.emit(i)
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(10)


class GuiClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  
        self.maxMethod1 = 1000
        self.maxMethod2 = 1777
        self.flagEnd = 2

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.qprogressbar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(objectName="qprogressbar",
                                               minimumWidth=400, minimumHeight=50)
        self.qprogressbar.setMaximum(self.maxMethod1)
        self.qprogressbar.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.qprogressbar.valueChanged.connect(self.qprogressbar_value_changed)
        self.qprogressbar.setFormat('процент выполнения: %p%, текущая value: %v, maximum value: %m')
        self.qprogressbar.setInvertedAppearance(True)

        self.qprogressbar_2 = QtWidgets.QProgressBar( objectName="qprogressbar_2", 
                                               minimumWidth=100, minimumHeight=200)
        self.qprogressbar_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)  
        self.qprogressbar_2.setMaximum(self.maxMethod2)
        self.qprogressbar_2.valueChanged.connect(self.qprogressbar_value_changed)

        self.qpushbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('&Start')
        self.qpushbutton.clicked.connect(self.qpushbutton_clicked)

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        self.mc = MyClass()
        self.mc.dataMethod1.connect(self.qprogressbar.setValue)
        self.mc.dataMethod2.connect(self.qprogressbar_2.setValue)

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlayout.addWidget(self.qprogressbar)
        vlayout.addStretch() 
        vlayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.qpushbutton)     

        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        hlayout.addLayout(vlayout)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.qprogressbar_2)        

    def start(self):
        threading._start_new_thread(self.mc.method1,(self.maxMethod1,))
        threading._start_new_thread(self.mc.method2,(self.maxMethod2,))


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def qpushbutton_clicked(self):
        self.qprogressbar.reset()
        self.qprogressbar_2.reset()
        self.qpushbutton.setEnabled(False)

        self.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def qprogressbar_value_changed(self, value):
        if self.sender().objectName() == "qprogressbar" and value == self.qprogressbar.maximum()-1:
            self.qprogressbar.setValue(self.maxMethod1)
            self.textEdit.append("Задача `method1` выполнена. Делайте что-нибудь.")
            self.flagEnd -= 1
        if self.sender().objectName() == "qprogressbar_2" and value == self.qprogressbar_2.maximum()-1:
            self.qprogressbar_2.setValue(self.maxMethod2)
            self.textEdit.append("Задача `method2` выполнена. Делайте что-нибудь.")
            self.flagEnd -= 1

        if not self.flagEnd:
            self.qpushbutton.setEnabled(True)
            self.textEdit.append("\nЗадачи `method1 и method2` выполнены. Надо что-то Делайте!\n")
            self.flagEnd = 2

qss = """
#qprogressbar_2 {
    border: 1px solid #76797C;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
#qprogressbar_2::chunk {
    background-color: #05B8CC;
}
"""            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    mw = GuiClass()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```py
import threading
class MyClass(QObject):
    def method1(self):
        for i in range(1, 1000000):
            pass

    def method2(self):
        for i in range(1, 1000000):
            pass

class GuiClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mc = MyClass()
    def start(self):
        threading._start_new_thread(self.mc.method1,())
        threading._start_new_thread(self.mc.method2,())
```

Попробуйте как-то так.

И, сдаётся мне, Вы `range` с `round` перепутали, ибо Ваша запись с `round` не имеет логического смысла. Она запускает цикл, повторяемый один раз. Скажу даже больше: я проверил, оно просто не запустится.

Также хочу заметить, что, т.к. в Вашем вопросе была поставлена задача только **запустить** выполнение методов в разных потоках, я не заботился об ожидании завершения их работы.

Comment: Да! range с round перепутал. threading.start_new_thread в python 3 это работает?

Comment: @МурадЯхьяев Я поправил, добавьте `_` в начале к названию метода

Comment: Ожидание завершения их работы, реализовывать с помощью Lock?

Comment: @МурадЯхьяев По-моему `Lock` – это подобие мьютекса в Python. Ожидание завершения их работы: создать объекты, управляющие потоками (`Thread`), запустить их (`Thread.start()`), ждать завершения (что-то вроде `Thread.wait()`)

Comment: @МурадЯхьяев Здесь вроде есть что-то стоящее на эту тему: http://python-3.ru/page/import-threading